# Errors when saving a large amount of data from a Postgres query to a file

Tags: python, postgresql, csv, bigdata

My code

```
    def save_to_csv(self):
        query = str(self.Text1.get('1.0', 'end-1c'));
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        timestamp_str = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")
        filename = f"result_{timestamp_str}.csv"
        
        db = self.db_connect()
        cur = db.cursor()

        with open(filename, mode='w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csv_file:
            writer = csv.writer(csv_file)           

            cur.execute('select * from "base_cdek_bf"') №
            writer.writerow([desc[0] for desc in cur.description])  
            while True:
                rows = cur.fetchmany(1000)  
                if not rows:
                    break
                writer.writerows(rows)
        
        csv_file.close()
        cur.close()
        db.close()
```

The amount of data that is selected from the table is somewhere around 180 GB. When this code is executed, all available RAM is filled and various errors are issued. Sometimes a database connection error, sometimes a memory error or a warning that the available RAM has run out. I have tried many different methods of saving the query result to a file, but unfortunately none of them work. Tell me what is my mistake?

Last error:
cur.execute('select * from "base_cdek_bf"')
psycopg2.errors.InternalError_: could not read block 8810376 in file "base/214899/214911.67": Not enough space

But free space on my disk is 4TB.

My hardware:
Win 10 x64
RAM 64Gb
Proc 12*3.6Ghz
HDD 10TB free more than 4TB

i already tried:

- StringIO() + copy_expert
- fetchmany

Comment: Did you try Cursor.copy() ? That could be more efficient. https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/basic/copy.html

Comment: Yes, i used the "Writing data row-by-row" method, with the same result

Comment: And what if you let the database create the CSV using a plain COPY? (without parsing the result in Python)

Comment: This is by design. The driver [retrieves](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/blob/master/psycopg/pqpath.c#L816) query results on execute, storing them in RAM - so, instead of 4TB of disk space you'd need 180Gb of RAM.

Comment: What you can (and should) do instead of `select *`, is query objects by n at a time, slicing on primary key: `select * from db where PK > max_known_pk order by PK limit n`

Comment: @Marat: Ordering 180GB of data is not a trivial thing. Especially when you have order over and over again to get all data. If you can, let the database handle the CSV (using COPY) and let your python code pick up the complete file when ready.

Comment: @FrankHeikens you're right that using COPY is more efficient - I assumed OP can't do that for some reason. However, ordering on an indexed column is pretty cheap - and it definitely doesn't involve sorting the entire table

Comment: Change your cursor to a named cursor, e.g. `cur = db.cursor("some_name")` and see what happens.  That forces creation of a server-side cursor that allows `fetchmany()` to work like you probably think it should work.

Comment: cur = db.cursor("save_csv")

Comment: and got error
line 222, in save_to_csv
    writer.writerow([desc[0] for desc in cur.description])
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: The code worked with this fix:
with open(filename, mode='w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csv_file:
            cur.copy_expert(copy_sql, csv_file)

Thank you all very much!!!